# What is a "class label" re: databases

Tags: database, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

Large volumes of literature about data mining specify the existence (or absence) of "class labels" in databases; separate from tuples and attributes. What *exactly* are they referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class label is usually the **target variable** in classification.

Which makes it special from other categorial attributes. In particular, on your actual data it won't exist - it only exist on your training and validation data sets.

Class labels often don't reliably exist for other data mining tasks. This is specific to classification.